# How to keep same colors when converting CMYK image to RGB using PIL?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, jpeg

When converting a CMYK image to RGB my colors get inverted. I want to keep the same (visually) colors and remove exif data.

I need to do this to be able to display the converted image on any image or pdf viewer.

## Result (code below)

### Original CMYK

Image too heavy to upload -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9z2jejhasjqdoy/original.jpeg?dl=0

### Converted RGB

[image]

### Converted RGB after uncommenting `invert_pixels(image)`

[image]

### Converted using [TinyJPG](https://tinyjpg.com/) (this conversion works properly in PDF and other image viewers. I want to essentially recreate this image profile)

[image]

## Stack

- Python 3.5.9
- PIL 5.1.0

## Test code:

```py
image_filename = "original.jpeg"
image_file = open(image_filename, "rb")
image = Image.open(image_file)

orientate_image_using_exif(image)

image_data = list(image.getdata())

image_without_exif = image.convert("RGB")
image_without_exif.putdata(image_data)

# invert_pixels(image)

image_without_exif.save(
    u"RGB_{}".format(image_filename),
    progressive=True,
    icc_profile=image.info.get('icc_profile'),
    subsampling=0,
)
```

## Comments

- I'm converting to RGB only because metadata of the TinyJPG image shows that it is RGB
- Considering how much closer the pixel inversion got me, my guess is that I need to find the correct formula for each pixel conversion keeping the correct color
- `orientate_image_using_exif` has no impact on the final colors

## Question

- Can someone help me get this working correctly? Desired result is like TinyJPG image. It does do lossless compression. I don't want/care about that. I'm only interested in removing exif data (works) and keeping the correct colors (doesn't work)

Comment: Why do you convert your image to RGB at all? JPEG is able to hold CMYK/YCCK images directly.

Comment: I’m trying to achieve exactly what is shown in the last image. Same as that last image works, changing the original image to RGB seems to make it work in a PDF viewer. The original CMYK image when opened with a PDF viewer inverts the colors

Comment: Perhaps you should also remove icc_profile when converting the image to RGB.

Comment: Btw, the image you shared does not contain Exif data (APP1 marker segment).

Comment: Yes, it seems it doesn’t. Which means the issue is in how the color space is represented in different readers. Ideal solution would keep the same colors visually as the compressed tiny jpg image

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are doing here. I get a correctly coloured, stripped image with this code:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('original.jpg')
RGB = im.convert('RGB')
RGB.save('result.jpg')
```

I can see the *"ICC Profile"* in the original with `exiftool` like this:

```
exiftool original.jpg

ExifTool Version Number         : 12.00
File Name                       : original.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 5.1 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:11:27 12:08:27+00:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:11:27 12:09:49+00:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:11:27 12:08:43+00:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
DCT Encode Version              : 100
APP14 Flags 0                   : (none)
APP14 Flags 1                   : (none)
Color Transform                 : Unknown (RGB or CMYK)
Profile CMM Type                : Adobe Systems Inc.
Profile Version                 : 2.1.0
Profile Class                   : Output Device Profile
Color Space Data                : CMYK
Profile Connection Space        : Lab
Profile Date Time               : 2000:07:26 05:41:53
Profile File Signature          : acsp
Primary Platform                : Apple Computer Inc.
CMM Flags                       : Not Embedded, Independent
Device Manufacturer             : Adobe Systems Inc.
Device Model                    : 
Device Attributes               : Reflective, Glossy, Positive, Color
Rendering Intent                : Perceptual
Connection Space Illuminant     : 0.9642 1 0.82491
Profile Creator                 : Adobe Systems Inc.
Profile ID                      : 0
Profile Description             : U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2
Profile Copyright               : Copyright 2000 Adobe Systems, Inc.
Media White Point               : 0.7084 0.73595 0.57104
A To B0                         : (Binary data 41478 bytes, use -b option to extract)
A To B2                         : (Binary data 41478 bytes, use -b option to extract)
A To B1                         : (Binary data 41478 bytes, use -b option to extract)
B To A0                         : (Binary data 145588 bytes, use -b option to extract)
B To A1                         : (Binary data 145588 bytes, use -b option to extract)
B To A2                         : (Binary data 145588 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Gamut                           : (Binary data 37009 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Image Width                     : 4167
Image Height                    : 4167
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 4
Image Size                      : 4167x4167
Megapixels                      : 17.4
```

And I can see it has gone in the output file like this:

```
exiftool result.jpg

ExifTool Version Number         : 12.00
File Name                       : result.jpg
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 718 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:11:27 12:15:48+00:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2020:11:27 12:16:14+00:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:11:27 12:15:54+00:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Resolution Unit                 : None
X Resolution                    : 1
Y Resolution                    : 1
Image Width                     : 4167
Image Height                    : 4167
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 4167x4167
Megapixels                      : 17.4
```

**Keywords**: Image processing, Python, PIL, Pillow, EXIF, strip EXIF, profile, ICC profile, strip profile.

Comment: Thanks a lot taking the time and helping. Ok, it seems the main issue was simpler to fix than I thought. Just converting the opened image to RGB makes the PDF viewer also display it correctly.

Comment: However, the colors are different still if you compare the result of your code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fh3yunscl25mz4/result_stack.jpeg?dl=0 and the TinyJPG image. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: The issue is that the profile is affecting the colours and once you remove it they are gone, you need something that will apply the profile to modify the colours and then save the modified colours without the profile. Not sure what to suggest.